When speaking of NC/NO for a thermostat, what is considered the “normal” state?
For a relay, the N in NC/NO (“normal” in normally closed/normally open) refers to the state in which no power is applied to the control side. For a push switch, normal equals not pushed (thus NC = push to break, NO = push to make).
For thermostats, I had assumed that normal refers to the state below the threshold temperature (NC = closed when cold, NO = closed when warm). This is somewhat consistent in a physical sense (whether for a relay, push switch or thermostat, normal refers to the state in which no force or energy is being applied), and the terminology seems to be somewhat widely used.
However, I now got a Bticino timer-thermostat and found out the behavior of the contacts differs from that. The contacts are labeled NC, C (common) and NO, and the timer-thermostat has a summer and a winter mode. In summer mode, the contacts behave as I would expect, i.e. normal = cold(er than target temperature). Switching to winter mode, however, inverts the meaning – the NC contact is closed when the temperature is warmer than the target. In other words, normal refers to the state in which the target temperature has been reached (not colder in winter, not warmer in summer). This means that, in order for the valve actuator for my heating (which is being sold as NO) to function correctly, I have to connect it to the NC terminal. The manual also states that a heater should be connected to NO.
Did I get the terminology wrong or does Bticino use non-standard terminology here?
Edit: updated link to point to the product page; manuals are linked there

My assumption would be the same as yours, but you should include a link to the manual of your actual model.

@EdinFifić I updated the product link; manuals are linked there.

Industrially (which may well differ from HVAC practices) we distinguish between N.O./N.C. as the power-off state and heating vs. cooling controllers (and also output state on sensor failure). So there are actually 8 possibilities for a single output contact.

do you have one heating and a separate cooling system or do you just have one heating system?

@Rekcoj Bticino just produce the thermostat, to be used universally with the heating/cooling system of the customer’s choice. That can be a heating system or a combined heating/cooling system, see instruction sheet (linked in the product page).
